# R data manipulation - Rang condition in data.table / dplyr

Tags: r, data.table

In R I am conducting analyses on `df1` but I also need to pull data from the more detailed records / observations in `df2` and attach to `df1` based on certain conditions.

This is sample data comparable to my own:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5),
                  location=c("a", "a" , "a", "b" , "b" , "a", "a" ,"a" ),
                  actiontime=c("2020-03-10" , "2020-02-17" , "2020-04-22" , "2020-04-19" , "2020-04-20" , "2020-04-22" , "2020-03-02" , "2020-05-07" ) )

df2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1, 2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4, 5,5,5) , 
                  observation=c( "2020-03-09 01:00" , "2020-03-09 10:00" , "2020-03-10 05:00",  "2020-02-15 08:00" , "2020-02-16 09:00" , "2020-02-17 08:00",  "2020-04-16 14:30",  "2020-04-16 07:30" , "2020-04-17 15:00" , "2020-04-25 07:20" , "2020-04-18 10:00" , "2020-04-19 10:30",  "2020-04-20 12:00", "2020-04-21 12:00" , "2020-04-22 09:30" , "2020-04-24 23:00", "2020-04-23 17:30", "2020-03-01 08:00" , "2020-03-02 08:00" , "2020-03-03 08:00" ,  "2020-03-15 16:45" ,  "2020-03-16 08:00" , "2020-05-05 13:45" , "2020-05-06 08:00" , "2020-05-07 11:00") ,
                  var1=round(runif(25, min=10, max=60),0) ,
                  var2=c("Red" , "Blue" , "Yellow" , NA , "Yellow" , "Blue" , "Red" , "Yellow" , NA , NA , "Yellow" , NA , NA , NA , NA , NA , "Blue", NA , "Blue" , "Yellow" , NA , "Blue" , "Yellow" , "Red" , "Blue") )
```

In example how can I do the following procedures (preferably with data.table but if someone also would like to demonstrate with dplyr it is also nice) :

- Q1. If I decide the following rang  Blue > Red > Yellow . How can I then get the highest rang color in `df2$var2` among the observations related to same `id` (if any) attached to a new variable by respective `id` in `df1` ?
- Q2. In addition to rang as in Q1, how do I add condition to only select `var2` if the observation happens a day before `actiontime` in `df1` ?
- Q3 And to learn even more - how can the data that was pulled out of `df2` joined to `df1` in Q1 be updated on the record with the earliest observation by the `id` in `df2` - meaning just working on `df2` not involving `df1` (and the join).

The output for Q3 would be something like this:

```
   id      observation var1   var2   color
1   1 2020-03-09 01:00   37    Red   Blue
2   1 2020-03-09 10:00   35   Blue   <NA>
3   1 2020-03-10 05:00   27 Yellow   <NA>
4   2 2020-02-15 08:00   21   <NA>   Yellow
5   2 2020-02-16 09:00   37 Yellow   <NA>
6   2 2020-02-17 08:00   38   Blue   <NA>
7   3 2020-04-16 14:30   56    Red   <NA>  
8   3 2020-04-16 07:30   35 Yellow   Red
9   3 2020-04-17 15:00   40   <NA>   <NA>
10  3 2020-04-25 07:20   20   <NA>   <NA>
11  3 2020-04-18 10:00   49   <NA>   <NA>
12  3 2020-04-19 10:30   58   <NA>   <NA>
13  3 2020-04-20 12:00   37   <NA>   <NA>
14  3 2020-04-21 12:00   25   <NA>   <NA>
15  3 2020-04-22 09:30   16   <NA>   <NA>
16  3 2020-04-24 23:00   52   <NA>   <NA>
17  3 2020-04-23 17:30   46   Blue   <NA>
18  4 2020-03-01 08:00   16   <NA>   Blue
19  4 2020-03-02 08:00   14   Blue   <NA>
20  4 2020-03-03 08:00   21 Yellow   <NA>
21  4 2020-03-15 16:45   52   <NA>   <NA>
22  4 2020-03-16 08:00   40   Blue   <NA>
23  5 2020-05-05 13:45   13 Yellow   Red
24  5 2020-05-06 08:00   12    Red   <NA>
25  5 2020-05-07 11:00   11   Blue   <NA>
```

Comment: Thanx for tip about set.seed - will use it next time. This time only var1 is affected by random numbers which will not affect the output / solution. var1 is passive and was included just to demonstrate that there are other variables in df2 which needs to be joined with df1 as well as the variables included in the condition.

Comment: thanks for responding.  In the 'df1', I didn't understand other than the 'id', how you are matching

Comment: Thanks also to you. It is  correct that in df1 only id will be the matching variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 questions in one, I will try to answer them one by one.

#### Question 1

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to identify the highest ranked color in `var2` per `id` and wants to copy the color to a new column in `df1` for the matching `id`s.

This can be solved by turning `var2` into an *ordered factor*, aggregating `df2` by `id`, and adding the result to `df1` by an *update join*:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df2[, var2 := ordered(var2, levels = c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow", NA), exclude = NULL)]

str(df2)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    25 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ id         : num  1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
>  $ observation: chr  "2020-03-09 01:00" "2020-03-09 10:00" "2020-03-10 05:00" "2020-02-15 08:00" ...
>  $ var1       : num  15 58 12 35 11 25 24 54 14 15 ...
>  $ var2       : Ord.factor w/ 4 levels "Blue"<"Red"<"Yellow"<..: 2 1 3 4 3 1 2 3 4 4 ...
>  $ action_day : IDate, format: "2020-03-10" "2020-03-10" "2020-03-11" "2020-02-16" ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

So, we can find the highest ranked color per `id` by using `min()`

```
df2[, min(var2, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
```

> ```
>    id   V1
> 1:  1 Blue
> 2:  2 Blue
> 3:  3 Blue
> 4:  4 Blue
> 5:  5 Blue
> ```

which is rather trivial because all `id` groups include `Blue` in `var2`.

This can be appended to `df1` by an *update join*

```
df1[df2[, min(var2, na.rm = TRUE), by = id], on = .(id), color := V1][]
```

> ```
>    id location actiontime color
> 1:  1        a 2020-03-10  Blue
> 2:  2        a 2020-02-17  Blue
> 3:  3        a 2020-04-22  Blue
> 4:  3        b 2020-04-19  Blue
> 5:  3        b 2020-04-20  Blue
> 6:  4        a 2020-04-22  Blue
> 7:  4        a 2020-03-02  Blue
> 8:  5        a 2020-05-07  Blue
> ```

#### Question 2

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to filter `df2` so that only those rows are kept where the date of the `observation` in `df2` is exactly one day before an `actiontime` in `df1` (for the same `id`). This intermediate result is then processed in the same way as `df2` in Question 1, above.

The filtering is accomplished by a join operation but requires to coerce the character date `actiontime` and character date-time `observation`, resp., to numeric date type for date calculation.

```
df1[, actiontime := as.IDate(actiontime)]
df2[, action_day := as.IDate(observation) + 1L] 
keep_df2_rows <- df2[df1, on = .(id, action_day = actiontime), nomatch = NULL, which = TRUE]

keep_df2_rows
```

> ```
> [1]  1  2  5 14 11 12 18 24
> ```

`keep_df2_rows` contains the row numbers of those rows of `df2` which fullfil the condition that the `observation` has happened exactly one day before an `actiontime` in `df1` (for the same `id`).

Now, we can use the code of question 1 but use `keep_df2_rows` to filter `df2`:

```
df1[df2[keep_df2_rows, min(var2, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]
  , on = .(id), color := V1][]
```

> ```
>    id location actiontime  color
> 1:  1        a 2020-03-10   Blue
> 2:  2        a 2020-02-17 Yellow
> 3:  3        a 2020-04-22 Yellow
> 4:  3        b 2020-04-19 Yellow
> 5:  3        b 2020-04-20 Yellow
> 6:  4        a 2020-04-22   <NA>
> 7:  4        a 2020-03-02   <NA>
> 8:  5        a 2020-05-07    Red
> ```

#### Question 3

If I understand correctly, the final goal of the OP is to add the `color` column to `df2` instead of `df1` with the additional requirement that the only the row with the earliest observation within an `id` is to be updated.

This can be accomplished by an *update join* with a *look-up table* `lut` which contains the colors by `id` as described above and the earliest `observation` by `id`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, var2 := ordered(var2, levels = c("Blue", "Red", "Yellow"))]
setDT(df1)[, actiontime := as.IDate(actiontime)]
df2[, action_day := as.IDate(observation) + 1L]
keep_df2_rows <- df2[df1, on = .(id, action_day = actiontime), nomatch = NULL, which = TRUE]

agg1 <- df2[keep_df2_rows][!is.na(var2), min(var2), by = id]
agg2 <- df2[, .(observation = min(observation)), by = id]
lut <- merge(agg1, agg2, by = "id")
df2[lut, on = .(id, observation), color := as.character(V1)][]
```

> ```
>     id      observation var1   var2 action_day  color
>  1:  1 2020-03-09 01:00   23    Red 2020-03-10   Blue
>  2:  1 2020-03-09 10:00   29   Blue 2020-03-10   <NA>
>  3:  1 2020-03-10 05:00   39 Yellow 2020-03-11   <NA>
>  4:  2 2020-02-15 08:00   55   <NA> 2020-02-16 Yellow
>  5:  2 2020-02-16 09:00   20 Yellow 2020-02-17   <NA>
>  6:  2 2020-02-17 08:00   55   Blue 2020-02-18   <NA>
>  7:  3 2020-04-16 14:30   57    Red 2020-04-17   <NA>
>  8:  3 2020-04-16 07:30   43 Yellow 2020-04-17 Yellow
>  9:  3 2020-04-17 15:00   41   <NA> 2020-04-18   <NA>
> 10:  3 2020-04-25 07:20   13   <NA> 2020-04-26   <NA>
> 11:  3 2020-04-18 10:00   20 Yellow 2020-04-19   <NA>
> 12:  3 2020-04-19 10:30   19   <NA> 2020-04-20   <NA>
> 13:  3 2020-04-20 12:00   44   <NA> 2020-04-21   <NA>
> 14:  3 2020-04-21 12:00   29   <NA> 2020-04-22   <NA>
> 15:  3 2020-04-22 09:30   48   <NA> 2020-04-23   <NA>
> 16:  3 2020-04-24 23:00   35   <NA> 2020-04-25   <NA>
> 17:  3 2020-04-23 17:30   46   Blue 2020-04-24   <NA>
> 18:  4 2020-03-01 08:00   60   <NA> 2020-03-02   <NA>
> 19:  4 2020-03-02 08:00   29   Blue 2020-03-03   <NA>
> 20:  4 2020-03-03 08:00   49 Yellow 2020-03-04   <NA>
> 21:  4 2020-03-15 16:45   57   <NA> 2020-03-16   <NA>
> 22:  4 2020-03-16 08:00   21   Blue 2020-03-17   <NA>
> 23:  5 2020-05-05 13:45   43 Yellow 2020-05-06    Red
> 24:  5 2020-05-06 08:00   16    Red 2020-05-07   <NA>
> 25:  5 2020-05-07 11:00   23   Blue 2020-05-08   <NA>
>     id      observation var1   var2 action_day  color
> ```

Note that the result differs from the example table posted by the OP because OP's definition of `df2` is different to the example table.

Also note that I had to modify the computation of `agg1` because of an unexpected behaviour of `min(var2, na.rm = TRUE)` when an `id` group consists only of `NA`. (To reproduce the issue, try `min(ordered(NA), na.rm = TRUE)` vs `min(ordered(NA))`)

Comment: Look forward to epsiode 2 :) Thanx a lot ! Your skill and time is highly appreciated !

Comment: And thanx a lot for answering all 3 questions :) Very helpful !